# Minimum Distance of Subspace of Code with final zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, induction, coding-theory

Let $C\subset \mathbb{F}_{q}^n$ be an $[n,k,d]_q$ code with a basis $\mathcal{B}_0=\{b^{(1)},\dots,b^{(k)}\}$ (where $b^{(j)}=(b^{(j)}_1,\cdots,b^{(j)}_n)\in\mathbb{F}_q^n$).

We can define a code $C_l$ as a subspace $C_l\subset C$ for $l\leq k$ of dimension $k-l$ which satisfies the following condition:

> The last $l$ components of each codeword are equal to zero.

The following is an inductive construction for $C_l$:

For $C_1$, consider the $b^{(i)}$ for which $b^{(i)}_n\neq 0$. If there is only one such $i$, then $C_1 = \operatorname{span}(\mathcal{B}_0\setminus \{b^{(i)}\})$. If there are no such $i$, the result is obtained as before with any choice of $i$. Otherwise, there exists $j\neq i$ with $b^{(j)}_n\neq 0$, and so we can replace $b^{(j)}$ with $b'=b^{(j)}_n\cdot b^{(i)}-b^{(i)}_n\cdot b^{(j)}$, which satisfies $b'_n=0$. This process can be repeated until there is only one $i$, and then we return to the first case.

For $C_l$, we repeat the same process with $n$ replaced with $n-l+1$, and $\mathcal{B_0}$ repalced with $\mathcal{B}_{l-1}$, a basis of $C_{l-1}$.

Clearly the minimum distance of $C_l$ is greater than or equal to that of $C$, but how can I show that they are equal? Also, is there a simpler way to show that $C_l$ exists other than my construction, or at least a simpler way to express the construction?

Comment: if my answer is satisfactory, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

For each codeword pair $b^{(i)},b^{(j)}$ in $C$ the distance between them is related to the cardinality of the support of their difference, i.e.,
$$
d(b^{(i)},b^{(j)})=\#\{k: b_{k}^{(i)}\neq b_{k}^{(j)}\}
$$
by definition. If $b^{(i)},b^{(j)}$ are both in $C_\ell$ then by definition the
set $\{k: b_{k}^{(i)}\neq b_{k}^{(j)}\}$  of coordinates where they differ is disjoint from the set $\{n-\ell+1,n-\ell+2,\ldots,\ell\}$ of last $\ell$ coordinates implying that the pairwise distance in the subspace code $C_\ell$ between these two codewords is the same as before.

Thus the minimum distance of $C_\ell$ is the same as that of $C.$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand - just because the distances between codewords in $C_\ell$ is the same as $C$ doesn't mean that $C_\ell$ contains the same 'minimally distant pairs' as $C$ - what if all such pairs have non-zero final $\ell$ digits, or rather, why can't this happen?